# I'm crazy with it: Error: Cannot transition to abstract state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Hi I 'm developing an app with IONIC Framework and am developing the user validation and error have not let me go , I leave some details of logic I'm using:

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('skulApp', ['ionic', 'ionic-material', 'ionMdInput', 'ngCordova'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state, AUTH_EVENTS, _Auth_Service, sqliteService){


$ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard)
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

    if (window.StatusBar)
        StatusBar.styleDefault();

    sqliteService.preloadDataBase(true);
});

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next, nextParams, fromState) {
    if ('data' in next && 'authorizedRoles' in next.data) {
        var authorizedRoles = next.data.authorizedRoles;
        if (!_Auth_Service.isAuthorized(authorizedRoles)) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go($state.current, nextParams, {reload: true});
            $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.notAuthorized);
        }
    }

    if (!_Auth_Service.isAuthenticated()) {
        if (next.name !== 'login') {
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('login');
        }
    }
});
})
```

**app.config.js:**

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider, USER_ROLES) {

$stateProvider
.state('main', {
    url: '/',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/main.html'
})

.state('login', {
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})

.state('main.dashboard', {
    url: 'main/dashboard',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard.html',
            controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
        },
        'fabContent': {
            template: '<button id="fab-profile" class="button button-fab button-fab-bottom-right button-energized-900" ui-sref="main.edit"><i class="icon ion-edit"></i></button>',
            controller: function($timeout) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById('fab-profile').classList.toggle('on');
                }, 800);
            }
        }
    },
    data: {
        authorizedRoles: [
            USER_ROLES.admin, 
            USER_ROLES.teacher, 
            USER_ROLES.father
        ]
    }
})

.state('main.edit', {
    url: 'main/edit',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/edit.html',
            controller: 'EditCtrl'
        },
        'fabContent': {
            template: ''
        }
    }
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function($injector, $location){
        var $state = $injector.get("$state");
        $state.go('main.dashboard');
    });
    });
```

The error is:

```
Error: Cannot transition to abstract state '[object Object]'
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:40332)
    at Object.go (ionic.bundle.js:40262)
    at app.js:52
    at Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:23003)
    at Object.transitionTo (ionic.bundle.js:40395)
    at Object.go (ionic.bundle.js:40262)
    at app.config.js:210
    at check (ionic.bundle.js:39247)
    at update (ionic.bundle.js:39259)
    at Scope.$broadcast (ionic.bundle.js:23003)
```

Te line in app.js is that:

```
$state.go($state.current, nextParams, {reload: true});
```

Here I do not include services , constants, controls , policies, and others, if they consider it necessary I do know and update the question. Please i don't do! Help me

Comment: Can you give us some context on what state your are leaving and which state you are going to when the state change handler runs? It is apparently trying to go to your "main" state, but it's not clear to me how `$state.current` can be "main" when that is an abstract state.

Comment: Use `$state.current.name` ?

Comment: Yes i use this line, but i see the error: Error: Could not resolve '' from state ''

Answer (score 0):

Well if you open your broswer on '/' the only matching state is your abstract one. Since it's matching otherwise doesn't get executed.

Use this instead of otherwise to redirect to your dashboard.

```
$urlRouterProvider.when('/', '/main/dashboard');
```

Comment: The error persists, it remains the same , but I appreciate your answer: Error: Cannot transition to abstract state '[object Object]'

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to your **$stateChangeStart** method.

In case it enters the first couple of **if** conditions, this line:

```
$state.go($state.current, nextParams, {reload: true});
```

Will abourt your try to go to **/main/dashboard**, and the state will remain in **/**.

Comment: Ok, so this conditional is: if($state.current.name != '')
Or is diferent, i have amateur in angular